# RTMP: Is there such a linux command line tool?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, utilities, rtmp

I have looked everywhere to find a linux utility that will allow me to download rtmp streams. Not flv video but MP3 streams. The location of the streams I want to download are in this format.

```
rtmp://live.site.com/loc/45/std_fc74a6b7f79c70a5f60.mp3
```

Anyone know of such a command line tool? Or even anything close to what I am asking for?

I do not want full software applications and it would be great if it worked on Linux via Shell or something.

Thanks all

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One of the following should do, if you have `mplayer` or `vlc` compiled with RTMP access.

```
mplayer -dumpstream rtmp://live.site.com/loc/45/std_fc74a6b7f79c70a5f60.mp3
```

This will generate a `./stream.dump`.

```
vlc -I dummy rtmp://live.site.com/loc/45/std_fc74a6b7f79c70a5f60.mp3 \
    --sout file/ts:output.mpg vlc://quit
```

This will generate a `./output.mpg`.  You'll have to demux it to extract just the audio stream out.

Comment: Great, thanks! I have installed mplayer but I am not sure how to add or include rtmp support. Is there a command I can use to install it. I am using Fedora 10, yum as installer.

Comment: Hmm, actually it seems like mainline mplayer does not have RTMP support.  Unless you want to try patching and compiling mplayer yourself, I suggest using VLC instead.

Answer (score 13):

This question is old but this can help to another users with this doubt.
To download directly, without any conversion, there is two options (*the author of both programs is the same and the behavior is the same*):

- [RTMPDump](http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/). Example: `rtmpdump -r "rtmp://host.com/dir/file.flv" -o filename.flv`
- [flvstreamer](http://www.nongnu.org/flvstreamer/). Example: `flvstreamer -r "rtmp://od.flash.plus.es/ondemand/14314/plus/plustv/PO770632.flv" -o salida.flv`

And if you want download and convert the video at same time, the best way is use ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://server/live/streamName -acodec copy -vcodec copy dump.mp4
```

Answer (score 12):

I think the landscape has changed a bit since the time of some of the previous answers. At least according to the [rtmp wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol). It would appear that the **rtmp protocol specification** is open for public use. To that end you can use 2 tools to accomplish what the original poster was asking, `rtmpdump` and `ffmpeg`. Here's what I did to download a rtmp stream that was sending an audio podcast.

**step #1 - download the stream**

I used the tool [rtmpdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rtmpdump) to accomplish this. Like so:

```
% rtmpdump -r rtmp://url/to/some/file.mp3 -o /path/to/file.flv
RTMPDump v2.3
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
Connecting ...
INFO: Connected...
Starting download at: 0.000 kB
28358.553 kB / 3561.61 sec
Download complete
```

**step #2 - convert the flv file to mp3**

OK, so now you've got a local copy of the stream, **file.flv**. You can use `ffmpeg` to interrogate the file further and also to extract just the audio portion.

```
% ffmpeg -i file.flv
....
[flv @ 0x25f6670]max_analyze_duration reached
[flv @ 0x25f6670]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, flv, from 'file.flv':
  Duration: 00:59:21.61, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
```

From the above output we can see that the **file.flv** contains a single stream, just audio, and it's in mp3 format, and it's a single channel. To extract it to a proper mp3 file you can use `ffmpeg` again:

```
% ffmpeg -i file.flv -vn -acodec copy file.mp3
....
[flv @ 0x22a6670]max_analyze_duration reached
[flv @ 0x22a6670]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, flv, from 'file.flv':
 Duration: 00:59:21.61, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to 'file.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf52.64.2
    Stream #0.0: Audio: libmp3lame, 44100 Hz, 1 channels, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press [q] to stop encoding
size=   27826kB time=3561.66 bitrate=  64.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:27826kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.000116%
```

The above command will **copy** the audio stream into a file, **file.mp3**. You could also have extracted it to a wav file like so:

```
ffmpeg -i file.flv -vn -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 44100 -ac 2 file.wav
```

This [page](http://howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/) was useful in determining how to convert the flv file to other formats.