# Best way to convert RTMP to MP4

Tags: ios, html, video, php-5.3

I need to play an RTMP streaming in a website.

I want to run on iOS devices, but I know [RTMP](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28854/using-rtmp-streaming/) does not run on it.

So, my idea is to convert RTMP to some audio file (mp4, for example) and send it to the user and to play with HTML5. Do you have a better idea to do this work? I have PHP5 at server, but I have no idea about how to convert a continuous data (streaming) in a HTML5 compatible audio. For now, it's only an idea I have...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried rtmpdump, flvstreamer, mplayer and vlc. My stream is 24h online, and the files grow and grow (when the utility works)... myplayer and vlc do not recognize the stream. I need to stop the converter to use the file in this situation. If I create too many files to play each one, I hear a lot of "stops" at sound.

Comment: This question is similar, but does not convert the file on the fly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024632/rtmp-is-there-such-a-linux-command-line-tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no live format that works with html 5 . Mp4 can not be used as a live source as it is not a streaming format. The only built in support for Live audio/video on iOS is HLS.